# Installing wordpress in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: installation, xampp, wordpress

I downloaded wordpress3.6.tar.gz file from wordpress.org i want to move that from my default downloads folder to /opt/lampp/htdocs folder and also un-zip it please help me out with this i'm new to this ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a shell/Terminal

Dash -> Search for Terminal

Dash -> More Apps -> 'See More Results' -> Terminal

Dash -> More Apps -> Accessories -> Terminal

Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl + Alt + T

Once you have your Ubuntu terminal open do the following:

$ cd ~/Download

$ sudo mv wordpress3.6.tar.gz /opt/lampp/htdocs/

$ cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/

$ tar -xvzf wordpress3.6.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

You can move files/folders to /opt/lampp/htdocs only if you have super user rights. To open nautilus in super user modes use this command in the terminal:

```
sudo nautilus
```

After extracting wordpress, you can open it in your browser by going to the URL `http://localhost/wp-admin`